# jackosn JSON formatter is deserializing without appropriate validation

Tags: java, json, date, jackson, deserialization

I have a model where I need to accept only dates with the format "dd/MM/yyyy. For that I am using `jackson JsonFormat` .

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;
 
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator))
public class InventoryVolume {
 
  private UUID itemID;
 
  @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
  public Date inventoryStartDate;
 
  private UUID ItemSpecID;
 
}
```

Now I expect dates with format `dd/MM/yyyy`(max length 10) only to be accepted and rest all to throw an exception.

But looks like the only thing that is checked is "/" between dates.

All of these following formats are deserialized and converted to valid date!! Is this an expected behavior?

### Year

> "inventoryStartDate": "01/01/11ff"
> "inventoryStartDate": "01/01/11fff"
> "inventoryStartDate": "01/01/1111111111"
> "inventoryStartDate": "01/01/11"

### Month

> "inventoryStartDate": "01/35/11"

### Date

> "inventoryStartDate": "023466234/12/11"

Comment: By default it's using SimpleDateFormat which is lenient and I don't see any way to change that without rolling your own.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)